# disable cells based on another cell

Tags: ms-access

In Access 07 on a form:  I need to disable two cells based on a dropdown.  Another words, if the user picks "new" from the dropdown, two other cells get disabled. I beleive I will need to right-click the dropdown, build code, but I don't know the IF... script I need to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say your form includes a combo box named cboMyField which is bound to a field named MyField in the form's record source, and two text boxes: txtField2 bound to Field2; and txtField3 bound to Field3.

You could check the combo's value and set the Enabled property of the two text boxes appropriately by calling a procedure in your form's code module.

```
Private Sub SetButtonStatus()
    If Me.cboMyField = "new" Then
        Me.txtField2.Enabled = False
        Me.txtField3.Enabled = False
    Else
        Me.txtField2.Enabled = True
        Me.txtField3.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Call that procedure from the form's On Current event so the text box status will be set as you navigate between rows.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    SetButtonStatus
End Sub
```

Do the same for cboMyField's After Update event so the text box status will be updated based on a user change for cboMyField.

```
Private Sub cboMyField_AfterUpdate()
    SetButtonStatus
End Sub
```

**Edit, Trouble-shooting**: Since you're using Access 2007. Put the database in a trusted location and run it from there.  See [Get started with Access 2007 security](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/get-started-with-access-2007-security-HA010198047.aspx)

**Edit2**:
Change the SetButtonStatus procedure temporarily to check whether it even runs, and how it sees the combo box value if it does run.

```
 Private Sub SetButtonStatus()
        MsgBox "SetButtonStatus"
        MsgBox "Value of cboMyField is '" & Me.cboMyField & "'"
        If Me.cboMyField = "new" Then
            Me.txtField2.Enabled = False
            Me.txtField3.Enabled = False
        Else
            Me.txtField2.Enabled = True
            Me.txtField3.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Also add `Option Explicit` to the Declarations section (at the top) of your module.  Then select Debug->Compile from the VB editor's main menu.  That effort should tell us whether the code includes any names which VBA doesn't recognize.

**Edit3**: From private communication, the combo's bound field was numeric data type, so could never be equal to "new".  Therefore every time the procedure ran, it set text box Enabled property to True.

Comment: Your reply is Excellent, but after making the correct adjustments and putting it in, the fields do not change. I am not sure I am getting the first Sub in the correct place. You say to put it into the form's code module? when I insert a module, it's not inside the form, it's just a module.  How do you mot a module inside a form?

Comment: Yes, that is where I had put it. Sorry, you had to type that last comment. But, you have 3 Subs above.  If first one goes in Sub Form_Current (not SetButtonStatus like you have above), second in Form_Current and third in field_AfterUpdate...  I Obviously have the first one wrong.. I cn't find a place to put the first one that will make this work.

Comment: Everything seems correct, but nothing changes when the “New” is chosen.
Do I need to do anything to the SetButtonStatus – is it a function or something else?
Here is exactly what I am using to get it working.

Private Sub Form_Current()
    SetButtonStatus
End Sub

Private Sub cboEval_AfterUpdate()
    SetButtonStatus
End Sub

Private Sub SetButtonStatus()
    If Me.cboEval = "New" Then
        Me.txtField2.Enabled = False
    Else
        Me.txtField2.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Comment: I created a trusted location, put the Db there, checked the scripts and no changes happen no matter what is in the "cboEval"combobox.  I really appreciate you help with this and hope you have another suggestion.

Comment: The msgbox returns a value for each choice of the combo-box. I added the Option Explicit.  Debug showed me a statment under dirty that was not needed. With all that completed, it still does not disable the textfield.  So, the SetButton is being recognized, but the If is not doing anything. I've checked for type-o's and many combinations you have not suggested, but I still can't get it to change the Enabled on the txtField.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The If/Then/Else is not necessary. It could be replaced with         `Me!txtField2.Enabled = (Me.cboMyField <> "new") Me.txtField3.Enabled = (Me.cboMyField <> "new")`.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton I agree, David, but I decided the If/Then/Else might be easier for the OP to understand.  Anyway the OP sent me the db, and the problem all along was that the combo's bound field is numeric, so can never be equal to "new".

Comment: Thanks again HansUp - this helped me with a lot more things I still need to add.